# How to update nested components without updating parent

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a table with rows of job listing models. Within the table, it is possible to dispatch a bulk action onto the queue. In my parent component, I have an array `$bulkIds` and add an array of each dispatched bulk action. When the queue job is completed, I check whether the IDs for that job match the ones saved, and `emit` an event (`bulkActionCompleted`) if they match. This I receive on the nested components. I want to update the rows **only** within that array, but **without** updating the parent component. The user might be dispatching other queue jobs, or paginating to other results, etc. I don't want to interfere with the user.

I have tried working with `skipRender`, but you can't skip the rendering of a child, and as soon as the child updates, so does the parent.

*Within the parent html:*

```html
<div id="job-listings-table" class="table-body col-12 p-0">
    @foreach($jobListings as $index => $jobListing)
        @php
            $isInBulk = in_array($jobListing->id, array_merge(...$bulkIds));
        @endphp

        <livewire:employer.job-listings.index.parts.row :jobListing="$jobListing"
                                                                    :isInBulk="$isInBulk"
                                                                    :lastJobIds="[]"
                                                                    :wire:key="$jobListing->id . now()">

       </livewire:employer.job-listings.index.parts.row>

                    
   @endforeach
</div>
```

*Child component:*

```php
class Row extends Component
{
    public JobListing $jobListing;
    public bool $isInBulk;
    public array $lastJobIds = [];

    protected $listeners = [
        'bulkActionCompleted',
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.employer.job-listings.index.parts.row');
    }

    public function bulkActionCompleted($jobListingIds)
    {
        $this->lastJobIds = $jobListingIds;
        if (in_array($this->jobListing->id, $jobListingIds)) {
            $this->isInBulk = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR:** I want to update specific nested components without refreshing the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is *default* behaviour. Whenever I emit an event that gets caught by the child components, the parent doesn't get *"fully"* updated, when the function that emits the event uses `skipRender`. Adding `wire:ignore` to static items, fixed the issue that was caused when the function ran in the parent component.

I can however not explain why parts of the parent still got updated. I guess `skipRender` doesn't quite skip the render of the whole component.

To better explain, with `skipRender` called, the render function never even gets called, but if you have elements which you might have changed via JS (in my example, a dropdown that gets shown when at least one checkbox is selected), will be reset to its initial state. It seems to not re-render the DOM, but it does reset. By adding `wire:ignore` to these specific elements, the problem is resolved.